# Parse data into array

Tags: php, parsing

I'm creating a "quote database" for a TV show I'm a fan of, and I'm rewriting parts of it I don't particularly like. I came across my function to parse the data holding the quote and characters into an array that I can easily loop through and display. One of the features of the site is that you can have a single quote (one-liner) or a conversation between several characters. Right now I'm storing single quotes like this:

> [charactername]This is my witty one-liner.

And conversations follow the same pattern:

> [characternameone]How's the weather?
>
> [characternametwo]Pretty good, actually.

And so on. Here's the aforementioned parsing function:

```
function parse_quote($text)
{
    // Determine if it's a single or convo
    if ( strpos($text, "\n") != false )
    {
        // Convo
        // Let's explode into the separate characters/lines
        $text = explode("\n", $text);
        $convo = array();

        // Parse each line into character and line
        foreach ( $text as $part )
        {
            $character = substr($part, 1, strpos($part, ']') - 1);
            $line = substr($part, strlen($character) + 2);
            $convo[] = array(
                'character' => $character,
                'line' => $line
            );
        }

        return array(
            'type' => 'convo',
            'quote' => $convo
        );
    }
    else
    {
        // Single
        // Parse line into character and line
        return array(
            'type' => 'single',
            'quote' => array(
                'character' => substr($text, 1, strpos($text, ']') - 1),
                'line' => substr($text, strlen(substr($text, 1, strpos($text, ']') - 1)) + 2)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

It works as expected, but I can't help but think there's a better way to do this. I'm horrible with regular expressions, which I assume would come in at least somewhat handy in this situation. Any advice, or improvements?

Comment: Yeah, use a database :) SQLite maybe

Comment: `$text` is coming from the database; that's how it's stored. How would I improve that? Perhaps I should serialize the thing before storing it?

Comment: Well, you didn't mentioned that, so I guessed "flat-file" meant just like that. An improvement? Use a column (in a table associated to the quote) for the character name so you don't have to parse anything but just use a select on properly indexed columns. Way easier and way more performant

Comment: Doesn't sound like a very interesting TV show.

Comment: You don't need regex. Sure, you could do it in fewer lines with a regular expression, but regex is much slower so simple tasks such as this should be done with string functions.

Comment: @DamienPirsy, so store each part of the conversation in its own row and grab it all from the database? How would that be more performant than getting it all at once? For search reasons I do have a column for `single_character` and `convo_character` which, in the case of single quotes, I do use.

Comment: I wouldn't store it as a serialized array. Better to normalise it into two tables; maybe "quotes" and "lines".

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would change your data storage method. It would be much easier to deal with a serialized or JSON encoded string.

Instead of

```
[characternameone]How's the weather?
[characternametwo]Pretty good, actually.
```

you would have

```
array(
  [0] => {
    'name'  => "characternameone",
    'quote' => "How's the weather?"
  },
  [1] => {
    'name'  => "characternametwo",
    'quote' => "Pretty good, actually"
  }
)
```

Then when you read it out, there isn't any parsing.

```
function display_quote($input)
{
  for ($i=0, $n=count($input); $i<$n; $i++) {
    $quote = $input[$i];
    if ( $i > 0 ) echo "\n";
    echo $quote['name'] . ': ' . $quote['quote'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
        $character = substr($part, 1, strpos($part, ']') - 1);
        $line = substr($part, strlen($character) + 2);
        $convo[] = array(
            'character' => $character,
            'line' => $line
        );
```

you could try

```
        preg_match('#\[([^\]]+)\](.*)#ism', $part, $match);
        $convo[] = array(
            'character' => $match[1],
            'line' => $match[2]
        );
```

HTH